# How to call a Java's object from a program in Python?

Tags: java, python

I'm not a python programmer and there is a course in Coursera which asks to submit code in python.

But, there is flexibility in the course that as long as a specific method returns correct answer, it can be submitted.

I would like to create and call a Java's object from Python and accept the return values. Can we do that? Are there any other mechanisms to write an entire program in Java and receive an output in Python?

Comment: So, you have motorcycle course and you don't know how to ride one, so you put it on a trailer behind your car to participate in the course?

Comment: LOL. It's not related to Python per se. That is the way they accept assignements, through their scipts. I'm here to learn the logic/algorithms which I was told to be implemented in any language. Some one in the discussion stated that he/she uses F#. So, I was looking for a way to do it in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius

This library requires us to install cython and pyjnius through pip.

Here is the minimal example copied from the [QuickStart-Docs](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-example)

```
from jnius import autoclass

Stack = autoclass('java.util.Stack')
stack = Stack()
stack.push('hello')
stack.push('world')

print stack.pop() # --> 'world'
print stack.pop() # --> 'hello'
```

This thing worked effectively for my use. It needs JAVA_HOME variable to be in the path.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to run Python on JVM, it's called [Jython](https://wiki.python.org/jython/). With that, you can call Java objects' methods from Python code.

OTOH I have doubts that the Coursera course would alow you to submit code for some non-trivial setup. I'd ask them first. Also, porting a bit of Java code to Python should not be too hard, provided this code is an exercise, not industry-grade.

Comment: They don't allow Jython as far as I know. They have given a python file where I'm supposed to write my code in a function and submit it.

Comment: And I'd like to write code in that function to call the java class

Comment: Then, other than invoking a Java process as an external OS process, you can't access Java code. I'd rather go with porting of the relevant part to the other language, so that all your code is either Java or Python.